# why is super() used with in same class

Tags: python, class, machine-learning, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

```py
class AnomalyDetector(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(AnomalyDetector, self).__init__()
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(8, activation="relu")]) 
    
    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(140, activation="sigmoid")])
    
  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded
```

i learnt that we use super() to call a parent class method inside a child class . but in this case there is nothing like parent and child ,  its only one class . please help me understand this code entirely.

i was not able to understand why is super() used in this

Comment: Well, there's `AnomalyDetector` and its parent `Model`.

Comment: i don't understand , can you please elaborate . the arguement " model "  in  class autoencoder( model ) is nothing its just a parameter , it can be replace with x or y or z or any

Comment: The very first line of your code says `class AnomalyDetector(Model)`. That means you're creating a child class named AnomalyDetector, whose parent is named Model.

Comment: brother , this the only class in the model , there is not any other class , " Model " is just an arguement it can also be X or Y or Z

Comment: You seem to have a misconception on how inheritance works in Python. The "argument" to a class is its parent class. There can be multiple.

Comment: @hasan check out the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance. Note the syntax `class DerivedClassName(BaseClassName):` ... "derived" means "child class" and "base" means "parent class".

Comment: brother thanks , i appreciate the help , i now understod it . i thought "Model" is just a random arguement which can be X or Y or Z but its a tensorflow API

Answer (score 1):

The Super() function is used to give access to the methods and properties of a parent or sibling class.

So in your case, you are inheriting the **AnomalyDetector** from the Model from TensorFlow Keras API that will initialize important attributes such as the input and output shapes of the model.

Further **MODEL** is a parent class in Keras API that contains all the model classes. So by using the **super(AnomalyDetector, self).**init**()** method of the parent **model** class it calls all the attributes from the **AnomalyDetector** subclass and this allows AnomalyDetector to inherit and use the functionality and attributes of the parent Model class.

Comment: jazakallahu khairan , this explains i well